# Excel adding a comment onto a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to write a macro that when the user selects a cell in the spreadsheet and they click the button, a comment is added onto that selected cell. how would i go about doing that? i tried `range(A1).addcomment` and such but it did not seem to work, i don't know why, an error message always pops up and highlights the entire line but the message was not helpful at all. please help

i have tried this code here but it did not seem to work and gives me an error message

```
sub adding()
range(A1).addcomment
end sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub SetComment()
      With ActiveCell
         .AddComment
         .Comment.Text Text:="This is a comment"
      End With
   End Sub
```

Comment: you should also add `.Comment.Delete` for deleting previous comment, because if active cell already has a comment, you'd get run-time error 1004

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follows.   You must add the comment and then the comment text can be edited.

```
Range("H13").Select
Range("H13").AddComment
Range("H13").Comment.Visible = False
Range("H13").Comment.Text Text:="Name:" & Chr(10) & "Test Comment" & Chr(10) & ""
```